# Airwatch and Office365 integration

Tags: office365, mdm, airwatch

My organization is using Airwatch as a MDM tool. We have a office 365 environment which is integrated with AD and we'd like to see if we can provision the users using existing office 365 environment without manually creating accounts in AirWatch. Has anyone tried  this before and please pass any reference if so ?

Thanks

Comment: sorry the tags might be confusing, SO won't let me add AirWatch tag.

Comment: Based on [this AirWatch page](http://www.air-watch.com/differentiators/enterprise-integration/directory-services), it looks like AirWatch already integrates with your on-premises AD. Is this what you already have?

Answer (score 2):

There is already an Application Access integration for AirWatch: [AirWatch: Connect to Windows Azure Active Directory](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/gallery/active-directory/airwatch/connect/). Note that Windows Azure Active Directory is where you have all the Office 365 user accounts.

Since this is SO, and SO is for programming questions, I'm going to assume you are looking to build your own application that does a customized integration for you. I'm going to further assume that the AirWatch APIs allow you to create new users.

You could do the following:

1. Use the [Windows Azure AD Graph Differential Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj836245.aspx) to detect when a new user is created.
2. Use the Airwatch APIs to provision the user in Airwatch.

Alternatively:

1. Use the [Windows Azure Active Directory Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974476.aspx) to create users (and, optionally, assign Office 365 licenses).
2. Use the Airwatch APIs to provision the user in Airwatch.

Comment: Thanks Philip. I had a look at the links given. Though they claim it is all possible , based on what is written here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn308588.aspx#bkmk_supportsso it looks like only certain applications have direct SSO integration with Azure AD. Further, no we are not writing any custom code to integrate with AW, but trying to utilize the out-of-the-box features to deploy some corporate apps in user devices.

Comment: Well, did you check if Airwatch has SSO? You still haven't said what kind of integration you're looking for. In your question, you mentioned you wanted provisioning. Now you've also mentioned you also want SSO. Also, is your Airwatch tied to your client's AD?